# Is there a way to update a foreign key field using an SQL Update Query in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two classes, and I am attempting to move a field from one to the other as efficiently as possible. The database is large, so it's ideal if we can use an [SQL Update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) within Django or a direct SQL query. My database is PostgreSQL.

```
Class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

Class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I know I can do this manually, but I was hoping to be able to run an SQL Update query like so:

```
Order.objects.all().update(address__name=F('name'))
```

But I'm not able to update a foreign key field using the update command. Any suggestions for an alternative either in Django or directly in SQL - as opposed to just writing out the following - is appreciated.

```
for order in Order.objects.all():
    address = order.address
    address.name = order.name
    address.save()
```

Comment: Your use case implies that for one Address model there would be only one Order and vice versa. In that case shouldn't you be using a `OneToOneField`? Otherwise your use case doesn't make sense as you might end up updating an address multiple times. Also why store duplicate data? shouldn't name only be in one of the models in this case?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes, ideally that class would use a `OneToOneField`, though in my current case it does not. Also, the name is on both models so as to facilitate the transfer of the `name` field, you could then remove the name field afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
orders = Order.objects.select_related('address')
addresses = []
for order in orders:
    address = order.address
    address.name = order.name
    addresses.append(address)
Address.objects.bulk_update(addresses, ['name'])
```

this should make only 2 SQL queries

but it is not well defined because one address can be attached to many orders

Comment: So the `select_related` in this case removes the additional query that would be expected from `order.address`, and the `bulk_update` prevents saving each individual address, correct? This is an excellent solution, thanks @Pawel.

Comment: correct :) you can turn on logging of queries of use Django Debug Toolbar to check the queries